# Telerik Reporting ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

please i have a question

I tried to use a condition IIF () in Fields , To assign sessions to a table format calendar Here is example :

```
= IIf(Fields.Day=”Wednesday” AND Fields.StartHour=8, Fields.Text)
```

Knowing that (Day and Text is string anf startHours is int)

And i get this error :

> **error has occurred while processing TextBox The expression contains undefined function call IIf()**

Answer (score 1):

IIf() syntax:

=IIf(bool expression, object truePart, object falsePart)

=IIf(Fields.Day=”Wednesday” AND Fields.StartHour=8, Fields.Text,"")

Your condition in last part is missing.
Please check it.